# Animated matplotlib imshow

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, imshow, random-walk

Let me first clarify that I'm not trying to generate random walk lines like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17322041/visualizing-a-2d-random-walk-in-python) and many other questions. I'm trying to make a random walk heat map that changes color as points are revisted, like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aIuhvV0tktU).

I've been able to create still-lifes like this:[image: results of random walk] but I want to see the process.

I can get the figure to show up, and if I print the array at each step I can see that the walk is working. But the figure itself doesn't animate. My code:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation as anim
import numpy as np
import sys
import random

length = int(sys.argv[1])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, length-1), ylim=(0, length-1))
arr = np.zeros((length, length), dtype = int)

cmap = mpl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('my_colormap',
                                                    ['black','green','white'],
                                                    256)
bounds=[0,0,10,10]
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)

im=plt.imshow(arr, interpolation='nearest',
              cmap = cmap,
              origin='lower')

x = int(np.random.random_sample() * length)
y = int(np.random.random_sample() * length)

def walk():
    global x, y
        rand = np.random.random_sample()
        if rand < 0.25 :
            if x == length - 1:
                x = 0
            else: x = x + 1
        elif rand < 0.5 :
            if x == 0:
                x = length - 1
            else: x = x - 1
        elif rand < 0.75 :
            if y == length - 1:
                y = 0
            else: y = y + 1
        else:
            if y == 0:
                y = length - 1
            else: y = y - 1
    return

def stand(arr):
    global x,y
    arr[x][y] = arr[x][y] + 1
    return arr

def animate(i):
    arr=im.get_array()
    walk()
    #print(a)
    arr = stand(arr)
    im.set_array(arr)
    return [im]

anim = anim.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=200, interval=20, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

Running Python 3.6, as you can see by the print.

There are so many videos with these animated grids and I can't find any answers! Somebody must know how to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `animated=True` and `vmin=0, vmax=255,` in the `imshow()` function below. I also changed the `stand()` line to `arr[x][y] = arr[x][y] + 10`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation as anim
import numpy as np
import sys
import random

length = int(sys.argv[1])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, length-1), ylim=(0, length-1))
arr = np.zeros((length, length), dtype = int)

cmap = mpl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('my_colormap',
                                                    ['black','green','white'],
                                                    256)
bounds=[0,0,10,10]
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)

im=plt.imshow(arr, interpolation='nearest',
        cmap = cmap, vmin=0, vmax=255,
              origin='lower', animated=True) # small changes here

x = int(np.random.random_sample() * length)
y = int(np.random.random_sample() * length)

def walk():
    global x, y
    rand = np.random.random_sample()
    if rand < 0.25 :
        if x == length - 1:
            x = 0
        else: x = x + 1
    elif rand < 0.5 :
        if x == 0:
            x = length - 1
        else: x = x - 1
    elif rand < 0.75 :
        if y == length - 1:
            y = 0
        else: y = y + 1
    else:
        if y == 0:
            y = length - 1
        else: y = y - 1
    return

def stand(arr):
    global x,y
    arr[x][y] = arr[x][y] + 1000
    return arr

def animate(i):
    global x,y
    arr=im.get_array()
    walk()
    #print(a)
    arr = stand(arr)
    im.set_array(arr)
    return [im]

anim = anim.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=200, interval=20, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

And I ran it with `length = 50` and I get an animation. See it [here](https://gfycat.com/gifs/detail/WellgroomedGlassBilby). So you may have to play around with your color choices a bit.

Comment: That's so strange. I'm running it with that change and am still just seeing a black box...

Comment: I see a black box only when I use `arr[x][y] = arr[x][y] + 1`. What versions of packages are you using?

Comment: Sorry, would you mind posting the entire script you're running, just so I can be totally sure there's no other differences? Also, are you running in Python 3?

Comment: I am sorry I forgot, I made minor changes to your script. I have posted the full code now.

Comment: Ah, that all did it! Thank you! Can you explain what ```vmin``` and ```vmax``` do? I can't believe I was so close

Comment: I can refer you to the documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html?highlight=matplotlib%20pyplot%20imshow#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow) because I am not an expert at this but from what I understand they are required to get the correct color maps.

Comment: Actually using `arr[x][y] = arr[x][y] + 10` gives the green color like you show in the figure. I have updated the answer.